# NullReferenceException using RenderControl with ASP.NET Menu Server Control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am getting a NullReferenceException exception when calling then RenderControl method of an ASP.NET menu server control.

I created the control dynamically using the following code:

```
private string RenderMenuHTML()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    string menuXML = MenuManager.GetMenuXML();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuXML))
    {
        Menu menuControl = new UI.Menu();
        menuControl.ID = "menu";

        // Required properties to use RenderControl
        menuControl.SkipLinkText = string.Empty;
        menuControl.StaticPopOutImageUrl = "fake.gif";
        menuControl.ScrollUpImageUrl = "fake.gif";
        menuControl.ScrollDownImageUrl = "fake.gif";

        // Data binding
        XmlDataSource xmlDS = new XmlDataSource();
        xmlDS.ID = "xdsMenu";
        xmlDS.Data = menuXML;
        xmlDS.XPath = "MenuItems/MenuItem";

        // Menu data binding
        MenuItemBinding menuItemBinding = new MenuItemBinding();
        menuItemBinding.DataMember = "MenuItem";
        menuItemBinding.ValueField = "Value";
        menuItemBinding.TextField = "Text";
        menuItemBinding.ToolTipField = "Text";
        menuItemBinding.NavigateUrlField = "NavigateUrl";
        menuControl.DataBindings.Add(menuItemBinding);

        menuControl.DataSource = xmlDS;
        menuControl.DataBind();

        menuControl.RenderControl(hw); // <-- Problem here
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

What I need to do is get the HTML code generated by the control so I don't have to manually generate it. I am binding an XML data source built from a recursive menu hierarchy.

I have looked at the details of the exception and the debugger doesn't seem to tell anything more.

Everything works fine when I am putting the control in a PlaceHolder, but what I need is the HTML code.

I seem to be missing some required properties from the Menu or MenuItem object, but I can't find anything relying to this on the web.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume that the control uses its context (ie things like the page it is on) to do something. While its not on a page it can't access this info which is why it worked in a placeholder and not outside of it. I'd suggest adding it to a placeholder in your page before calling your rendercontrol method. If you want to then remove it from the page afterwards there is nothing to stop you then doing so. I'm not sure if there may be side effects of this (eg you might need to be careful of some of the naming of IDs etc. since they may be dependent on where you put it in the page).

I would also go on to question what you are then doing with this HTML? If you are using it on a page why not just sit the control in the page and let it do its thing? If you are using it elsewhere then why not use static HTML? Not to say that what you are doing is wrong, I am just struggling to think of what you are doing so want to make sure you have definitely thought about why you are doing it this way. :)

Comment: I have a string containing HTML code that comes from a predefined template. I want to replace something like {Template.Menu} with the actual menu, so I tought I would just get the code using RenderControl.

Comment: @Jason: Ah, ok. that makes sense. There may be better ways of doing it than this but they might also be overengineered for what you are doing. ;-) I think what I've suggested should get you what you need though.

Comment: You're probably right, I guess I'll generate the code by hand using an HtmlTextWriter instead of the Menu control. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: When I said what I suggested would work I was more meaning that if you add the menu control onto the page first it would probably render to your htmltextwriter fine. You might want to make sure there is no context sensitive stuff there or if there is take measures to tweak it but I think it should be possible to keep doing broadly the method you started with. Just do Page.Controls.Add(menu) before the rendercontrol and Page.Controls.Remove(menu) or whatever the equivalent is after you've rendered it.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize your Control by using init Event

this is an example to initialize Menu control on an ASP page

```
    protected void Menu1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Category> categories = db.GetCategory();
        for (int i = 0; i < categories.Count; i++)
        {
            ((Menu)sender).Items.Add(new MenuItem(categories.ElementAt(i).Name));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to override the Render or RenderChildren events.

Here's an example from Microsoft

```
// Override default implementation to Render children according to needs. 
protected override void RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
   if (HasControls())
   {
      // Render Children in reverse order.
      for(int i = Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      {
         Controls[i].RenderControl(output);
      }
   }         
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
{       
   output.Write("<br>Message from Control : " + Message);       
   output.Write("Showing Custom controls created in reverse" +
                                                    "order");         
   // Render Controls.
   RenderChildren(output);
}
```

This works for me in a standard ASPX page:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb));
    base.Render(htw);
    writer.Write(sb.ToString());

    Logger.Write("TransferToColdFusion HTML: " + sb.ToString(), "Debug");
}
```

Try this method and pass in your menu control.

```
public string RenderControl(Control ctrl) 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    ctrl.RenderControl(hw);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: No error after overriding these methods, but sb.ToString() returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the control is relying on the page lifecycle to initialize some variable that is used in RenderControl.

You'll have to [Debug the .NET Framework Source Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx) to see what that is.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it worked perfectly alright.. the hw has this after the RenderControl method.

```
> <div id="menu">   <ul class="level1">
>       <li><a title="test" class="level1"
> href="www.google.com">test</a></li>
> 

</ul> </div>

The only difference was that I used a sample xml = @"<MenuItems><MenuItem Value='Test' Text='test' NavigateUrl='www.google.com'>Test</MenuItem></MenuItems>";
```

So might be something to do with your Menu Xml source.